# Generate heatmap in R (multiple independent variable)

Tags: r, heatmap

There are a few similar questions but they are not asking what I am looking for.
I have a gene expression data with multiple independent variables. I want to visualize it using a heatmap in R. I am not able to include all the three variables together on the heatmap. Below is the example code:

```
species <- rep(c("st", "rt"), each = 18)
life <- rep(c("5d", "15d", "45d"), 2, each = 6)
concentration <- rep(c("c1", "c2", "c3"), 6, each = 2)
gene <- rep(c("gene1", "gene2"), 36, each = 1)
response <- runif(36, -4, 4)
data1 <- data.frame(species, life, concentration, gene, response)
```

I am open to use any package. Please see below image which is from a different dataset. I wish to visualize my data in a similar manner.

[example_data_visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avgbg.jpg)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which of the variables in your code correspond to which of the dimensions in your chart but, using the `ggplot2` package, it's quite easy to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data1, aes(x = factor(life, levels = c("5d", "15d", "45d")), 
                  y = concentration, 
                  fill = response)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  facet_wrap(~species + gene, nrow = 1) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", guide = FALSE) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "life")
```

Of course, you can adjust the titles, labels, colours etc accordingly.